# Nested form not updating the database

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nested-forms

I have a nested form that does not update the database.

**Models:**

User:

```
has_many :designs, :dependent => :restrict

accepts_nested_attributes_for :designs

attr_accessible :designs_attributes
```

Design:

```
belongs_to :user
```

**Designs Controller:**

```
def update
    @design = Design.find(params[:id])
    @user = User.find_by_id(@design.user_id)
    @points = (@user.points + 5000)
    if @design.update_attributes(params[:design])
        flash[:success] = "Design aproved"
        redirect_to designindex_path
    else
        @title = @design.name + %(, created by ) + @design.user.username
        render 'edit'
    end
end
```

And here is the form:

```
<%= form_for @user, :html => { :multipart => true } do |f| %>
    <%= f.hidden_field(:points, {:value => @points}) %>
    <%= f.fields_for :designs, @design do |d| %>
        <div class="field">
            <%= d.label :total_price, %(New price) %><br />
            <%= d.text_field :total_price %>
        </div>
        <%= d.hidden_field(:aproved, {:value => 1}) %>
    <% end %>
    <div class="actions">
        <%= f.submit "Submit" %>
    </div>
<% end %>
```

Also, when I push Submit button, it redirects me to root_path.

Looking in the console output I found this:

```
Started POST "/users/101" for 127.0.0.1 at 2011-09-29 15:31:16 +0200
Processing by UsersController#update as HTML
Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓",
"authenticity_token"=>"N16nb5i/PUPftGHs3uvnnLwrp8e/PQB88w0OU6DLGko=",
"user"=>{"points"=>"7500", "designs_attributes"=>{"0"=>{"total_price"=>"20",
"aproved"=>"1", "id"=>"66"}}}, "commit"=>"Submit", "id"=>"101"}
```

The problem here seems to be the following:

An user has_many designs, but when doing the POST request the controller does not specify which one is being updated. Anyway, the users.points attribute is neither updated.

**Update**

Ok, I got the problem, I have this in users_controller.rb:

```
before_filter :authenticate, :only => [:index, :edit, :update, :destroy]
before_filter :correct_user, :only => [:edit, :update]
```

And I'm trying to update another user's information from an admin account. Can I do this in any way?

Here is the code for those:

```
def correct_user
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
    redirect_to(root_path) unless current_user?(@user)
end

def current_user?(user)
    user == current_user
end

def authenticate
    deny_access unless signed_in?
end

def signed_in?
    !current_user.nil?
end
```

Comment: You'll need to post the contents of `correct_user`/`authenticate` to tell.  but it definitely seems to be your before_filter if you're being redirected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll want to do:

```
<%= f.fields_for :designs, @design do |d| %>
  ...
<% end %>
```

This will make sure it uses the `designs_attributes` attribute (and will default to 0 index I believe).  Can't remember if you'll need to wrap the `@design` in an array (`[@design]`), don't believe you do.

Your params should look like `{:user => {:designs_attributes => { '0' => {:id => 1, ... } } } }`

Comment: Tried that (both @design and [@design]) and is not working either... I'll update the cuestion now with the new code and params.

Comment: You'll need to add :points to attr_accessible as well to make it setable. Can you add attr_accessible to all the fields you need on `Design` as well.   Your params are looking good, it is specifying the  design you want to update based on the id being passed in

Answer (score 0):

Ok, got it working, just modified correct_user function as follows

```
def correct_user
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
    redirect_to(root_path) unless current_user?(@user) || current_user.admin
end
```